# Subscription could not be found in Azure Management API

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service, azure-management

I'm trying to create a Kubernetes cluster using Azure Management API.

```
  var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"));


  var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();

var kubernetesCluster = azure.KubernetesClusters.Define("aks").WithRegion(Region.EuropeWest)
        .WithNewResourceGroup("aksResourceGroup").WithLatestVersion().WithRootUsername("aksUsername")
        .WithSshKey(sshPublicKey).WithServicePrincipalClientId("clientId")
        .WithServicePrincipalSecret("secret").DefineAgentPool("ap").WithVirtualMachineCount(1)
        .WithVirtualMachineSize(ContainerServiceVirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardA0).Attach()
        .WithDnsPrefix("dns-aks").Create();
```

In the last line, a CloudException is thrown with the message: Subscription [] could not be found.

Even though an exception is thrown, the resource group is created but it is empty.

I have logged-in using Azure CLI with that service principal and I have run

```
az account list
```

with the following response:

```
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "SUBSCRIPTION ID FROM EXCEPTION ABOVE",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Pay-As-You-Go",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "xxx",
    "user": {
      "name": "xxxx",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

The App registration exists In Azure Active Directory > App registrations > All apps. I even gave permissions to all possible APIs.

Is there anything I did wrong in order to receive that exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error log, it seems you don't set default subscription for your service principal. You could use `az account set --subscription <name or id>` to set it.

If it still does not work, I suggest you could use the following code.

```
  var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .withSubscription("subscription id")
```

Note: You should give your service principal Owner role on your subscription level. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role). But it seems you had done it, but I suggest you could check again.

Comment: I have tried to create another service principal using Azure CLI, I have set the subscription as you said. The service principal is Owner. https://imgur.com/a/6vNzx . The exception is still thrown.

Comment: Do you try use `.withSubscription("subscription id")` to set subscription id?

Comment: Yes. Inside Response property from exception I am getting {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Subscription c83fbcef-1664-4ccf-bf94-439b37XXXXXX could not be found."
 }

Comment: How do you set the auth file, it seems you configure has some issue. Check this link  https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md

Comment: Or check this [project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aks-dotnet-manage-kubernetes-cluster) on GitHub.

Comment: This is the sample that I am trying to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168093/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-ciubotariu-florin).